# Rails - Iterating through method names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through method names in my controller. This is what I have so far but of course this won't work. I've seen other posts about using 'send'. But couldn't get that to work right. Any suggestions?

```
@someMethods = {
  '0' => 'methodone',
  '1' => 'methodtwo'
}

for count in 0..1
  @someObject[count] = Trucks.@someMethods["#{count}"](params[:color])
end
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@someMethods.each do |count, method|
  @someObject[count] = Trucks.send(method, params[:color])
end
```